# Seeing all the values of variables in python as it is run

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, python-3.x

In MatLab, unless I add ; at the end of the line, I can just run and see what this code is doing. For example if I code

```
x=0
for i=1:1:3
    x=x+1
end
```

then I will see that

```
x=0
x=1
x=2
x=3
```

appearing in the window.

That way, I can see the process of my code, and so I can easily fix the error when there is.

How can I do the same thing in Python?

I know I can just add print to make it happen like

```
for i in list
    print('i is:', i)
    i=i+1
```

But this makes the whole code too messy. Is there a MatLab-like way to do this?

Comment: are you using an editor, or, we pray, an IDE for writing your python?

Comment: @Shawn_Mehan Thank you! I just use note++ or sublime text for an editor. Thanks to your hint, I searched Python IDE and found good pages.  Which python IDE have the feature of showing the variables as it is run? (preferably, only a specific portion of the variable if it's too huge.)

Comment: related: [`macropy.tracing`](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy#tracing)

Comment: All of them that have a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with matlab, but from what you are explaining, you seem to be wanting to trace your code to see where errors come up? You can do this through pdbtrace.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Here is a quick how-to on how to use pdbtrace using your code sample:

```
import pdb
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
pdb.set_trace()
for i in l:
    print('i is:', i)
    i = i+1
```

So, when you run this, you will then have the ability to control the flow of the app. You hit 'n' for the next step in your code, and you can see what it is doing.

I strongly suggest reading this, as it is an excellent tutorial:

https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/

Furthermore, what I actually recommend even more, is using an IDE that has a fully functional debugger. I am partial to PyCharm, which you can download for free here: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/

Comment: Thank you! This package looks worth it in and of itself. Does PyCharm show me the values of the variable whenever the value of it changes while running the code?

Comment: yes. You can set a `watch` on a variable or even an expression. Also, PyCharm has a nice display of the variables in scope as you step through the program.