# Python code to generate an alternative python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Related:[Seeing all the values of variables in python as it is run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33073650/seeing-all-the-values-of-variables-in-python-as-it-is-run)

I wanted to see the value of variables whenever the value of the variable change, so that I can easily spot where I wrongly coded.

I know if I add lines like

```
print('i=',i)
```

then I can see it, but it 1) makes whole code dirty, 2) takes long time to add these lines.

So if I have a something like print_adder.py  that automatically changes code.py and save it as code2.py, that will be great. Can it be possibly done?

code.py

```
i=0
for i in list:
    i=i+1
```

code2.py

```
i=0
print('i=', i)
for i in list:
    i=i+1
    print('i=', i)
```

And would it be also possible to show only small portion of the value if it the variable is too large like 10000 element list?

Comment: What's your question? "Can it be done?" Sure, that's what code injection is all about.

Comment: Have you heard of debuggers? Sounds like you just want to run your code under `pdb`.

Comment: First rethink about your requirements. And then search/use already existing constructs like a debugger and don't create your own inefficient construct (may just to teach yourself).

Comment: I don’t see how it could be possibly useful to print out a variable’s value at *every point* where it is changed, especially without any context. If this is for debugging purposes, then you should use a debugger to locally extract the values you are interested in. And if this isn’t for debugging, then my question is a big “why do you want to do this?”.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I will try pdb